# Project ideation using image processing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, pixel-manipulation

I am in my final year of BS Computer Science. I have chosen a project in the image processing domain. But I really don't know where to start from! Here is a rough draft of my project idea:

**Project Description:**

Often people are faced with the problem of deciding which colors to choose to paint their walls, doors and ceilings. They want to know how their rooms will look like after applying a certain color. We want to design a mobile application that can give people the opportunity to preview their rooms/walls/ceilings, etc, with a certain color before applying the color.  Through our application the user can take photos of their rooms/walls/ceilings, etc, and change their colors virtually and preview them. This will give them a good estimate about the final look of their house.

Development will be in java using open CV libraries.
Can anyone provide some help?

Comment: I doubt anybody from stack overflow will "guide" you. This really isn't the forum to ask for guidance.

Comment: The best thing would be to start with a good computer vision book that includes a chapter about different color spaces. If you know how color is represented in different color spaces you will surely find a way to manipulate the colors to your likings.

Comment: Sounds far too difficult for a final year project. You really should consider a different project.

Comment: @GilLevi its late now have to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starting OpenCV with android you can follow the tutorial [here](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html).

And as your above description, I think you need to do the following...

1. Filter out the color of room's  wall or ceiling color.
2. Replace with your preview color.

But as your room's color is not unique, you may need to mark the color manually and segment it. Here [watershed](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html) algorithm might be helpful.

And one more thing is that there might be a chance of lighting variation, so you should use [HSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472716/why-is-color-segmentation-easier-on-hsv) color space instead of RGB.

And finally this is not the full solution, but you will get some idea about how to start with your project.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick as a famous image processing library.You may look that one too.It can perform numerous operations with images

Thanks